# How to implement a “loading screen”?

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point, time.h

Is there a way to call loading_screen() then clear the screen after three seconds and then go in with the programm??

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
    void loading_screen() {
        printf("\n*\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\n* Welcome to your blah blah! *\n*\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\n\n");
    }
    
    void starting_screen() {
        printf("1. add new recipe\n");
        printf("2. search for recipe\n");
        printf("3. delete recipe\n");
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        loading_screen();
        starting_screen();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: Are you trying to make it look like a "real" program? "Real" programs are so fast they don't need loading screen!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `system("cls");` on windows or `system("clear");` on linux :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
    
    void loading_screen() {
        printf("\n*\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\n* Welcome to your blah blah! *\n*\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\t *\n\n");
    }
    
    void starting_screen() {
        printf("1. add new recipe\n");
        printf("2. search for recipe\n");
        printf("3. delete recipe\n");
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        loading_screen();
        sleep(3);
        system("cls");//system("clear");
        starting_screen();
        return 0;
    }
```